# Should I keep the '#theme_wrappers' => array() for form fields?

Tags: 8, forms

I am migrating a few custom modules from Drupal 7 to drupal 8 that contain a lot of forms built using the form api and contain fields like this one:

```
$form['type_document'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Type de document'),
    '#options' => $types_document,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('form-control')),
    '#theme_wrappers' => array()
);
```

I am not sure if I should keep the `'#theme_wrappers' => array()` or not and also the `form-control` classes.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: An empty theme wrappers array did nothing in D7 and won't do anything in D8 either. The form-control class is not used by any core themes in D8 but is used by Bootstrap so might have some effect if you have a Bootstrap based theme. Strictly speaking adding the class should be done in the theme but it won't be harmful to add it in a custom module.

Comment: In situations like this, I would drop them both. See if it has adverse affects. See if putting them back fixes it.

Comment: I don't think '#theme_wrappers' => array() with an empty array has any effect.